# Is there a way to make a beacon face horizontally?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to make a beacon face horizontally with a command block? What is the command?

Answer (score 2):

**No**. Beacons don't have any sort of direction data, so you can't manipulate the direction it faces in any way.

Comment: Even if you somehow managed to hack the block into facing a different direction, the beam will still project vertically as well.